# How to add the key with value for each object inside an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have this array of objects and I want to add the value of the object below in the same order as it is inside the items array, Any suggestion?

```js
const items = [{
    tshirt: "Model TS",
    jeans: "ModelXW",
  },
  {
    sneakers: "indcdsc54",
    furniture: "Table31S"
  },
  {
    dress: "indc54",
    short: "shortS2"
  },
];
```

either an object or an array, which one should be easier?

```
const obj = [
  "localhost:8080.com",
  "localhost:3000.com",
  "localhost:7000.com",
]
```

Expected output:

```
const items = [{
    tshirt: "Model TS",
    jeans: "ModelXW",
    website: "localhost:8080.com",
  },
  {
    sneakers: "indcdsc54",
    furniture: "Table31S",
    website: "localhost:3000.com",
  },
  {
    dress: "indc54",
    short: "shortS2",
    website: "localhost:7000.com",
  },
];
```

I have tried this way with no success, any suggestion?

```js
const items = [{
    tshirt: "Model TS",
    jeans: "ModelXW"
  },
  {
    sneakers: "indcdsc54",
    furniture: "Table31S"
  },
  {
    dress: "indc54",
    short: "shortS2"
  }
];

const obj = [
  "localhost:8080.com",
  "localhost:3000.com",
  "localhost:7000.com",
]

let newArray = obj.map(uri => items.map(i => i["website"] = uri ))

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: I would assume `obj` should be an array as it currently throws a syntax error. Plus objects do not have a `.map` method

Comment: My bad obj is an array :) @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this, assuming the uris are in an array

```js
const items = [{
    tshirt: "Model TS",
    jeans: "ModelXW"
  },
  {
    sneakers: "indcdsc54",
    furniture: "Table31S"
  },
  {
    dress: "indc54",
    short: "shortS2"
  }
];

const uris = [
  "localhost:8080.com",
  "localhost:3000.com",
  "localhost:7000.com",
]

let newArray = items.map((item,i) => (item.website = uris[i], item)); 
// OR          items.map((item,i) => ({website : uris[i], ...item}));
console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: I have two versions. Did you see them both? Interesting ways, comma operator or object spread

Comment: Yeah, For the first option what does the item mean " uris[i] , item" in this case?

Comment: I set the website and return what’s after the comma

Comment: Gotcha like saying pass the rest of the values of the object. thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it your `obj` constant should be an array since you don't have any keys in there and assuming that your `items` are in the same order this should be enough.

```
const newArray = items.map((item,index) => {
  item.website = obj[index];
  return item
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Make obj an array

```js
const obj = [
  "localhost:8080.com",
  "localhost:3000.com",
  "localhost:7000.com",
]
const items = [{
    tshirt: "Model TS",
    jeans: "ModelXW",
  },
  {
    sneakers: "indcdsc54",
    furniture: "Table31S"
  },
  {
    dress: "indc54",
    short: "shortS2"
  },
];


obj.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (index < items.length) items[index].website = item;
})

console.log(items)
```